# Error in php redirect

Tags: php, redirect, button, header, translation

I have a button:

```
<form method="post">
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="icon2" value=" " />
</form>
```

And a redirect with a header using following code:

```
<?php
$homepage = '/2013/php/nelson-test.php';
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $homepage==$currentpage)
{
header('Location:/2013/php/nelson.php');
}
?>
```

I used the exactly same code yesterday in a different site and it works (I only changed the links), and now it gives me this error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homez.121/pneuexpo/www/2013/php/nelson-test.**php:1**) in /homez.121/pneuexpo/www/2013/php/nelson-test.php on **line 6**
```

I don't understand why since in line one I only have the php beginning tag and on line 6 there is only the header. Any ideas?

(BTW the purpose of the button and the header is that when you click the button it redirect to the same page but in English (the page is currently in French))

Comment: You might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php

Comment: `header('Location:/2013/php/nelson.php');` works only when there is no html print out yet.

Comment: already read it :/
@ModestasStankevičius no,, there is no html code :/ that is why I don't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
echo("<script>location.href = '/2013/php/nelson.php';</script>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove ';' after this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $homepage==$currentpage)   //Remove ;
{
    header('Location:/2013/php/nelson.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: It gets the same, I only put it to see if with that it ill work and forget to take it off, sorry

Comment: +1, also, if the errors saying line 1, make sure there isn't any whitespace or new lines prior to the `<?php` tag

Comment: And one more thing try to put exit after the header line like in my edit

Answer (score 0):

yes that is correct remove ; from it if you put ; then it interprete as a statement and it will raise error, and before header there should not be output on the page.

Comment: there is no whitespace and it does not have ';'

Comment: remove all white space after <?php

Comment: still if you cant do it then redirect using javascript  echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="nelson.php"</script>';

Comment: There is no space..  and @jay told to use a script that works

Answer (score 0):

as i am gussing your if condition is valid then please add `exit`

```
<?php
$homepage = '/2013/php/nelson-test.php';
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $homepage==$currentpage);
{
header('Location:/2013/php/nelson.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove all white space after

still if you cant remove error than redirect using javascript as follow

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="nelson.php"</script>';
```